# iOS app uploaded via XCode but not showing in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

This is the first time I have uploaded an app to iTunes Connect via Xcode. Is there a time delay for it to show up in the build? I can't see it listed in iTunes Connect Activity tab either.

I have read some people have had issues because the Information Property List didn't have enough information. The app requires permissions for Location, Camera and Photo library usage. They are listed in the plist file but there is no value set for any of them - is that the problem?

Comment: Wait for some time, it will show you.

Comment: Check your registered mail, it might cancled

Comment: Are you using Firebase?
I've had a similar problem and it was missing the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in the info.plist.

Comment: Sometimes, when I upload a new build, it doesn't show up on iTunes Connect, even if I wait some hours. In this case, you need to upload again your build and it will works !

Comment: @xylar you need to change build version on itunes connect like 5.0 not 5.1

Comment: I just waited 20min, then it showed up under section "Build" another option was showed up, once I clicked it, I was able to choose an archive version that wasn't used yet

Answer (score 1):

Once you uploaded an app via Xcode.It transmits the archive to Apple, where the build is examined to determine whether it conforms to Apple guidelines.
In my case probably it tooks more time at first build.Rest of other version builds are moved quickly.

Check your registered mail in iTunes.Once app review was done you will be notified whether success or failure.

You can able to see in window which present when clicking select build in itunes.There you can see something like **build processing** once you uploaded your build.

If description is missed for Cocoa keys then probably app will be reject by iTunes connect. It will notify somthing like missing usage descriptions.

> **Important** :
>
> For eg
>
> In .plist when using Cocoa keys something like `Privacy - Camera Usage
>   Description`.Then specifies the reason for your app to access the
>   device’s camera.

You must add description of Cocoa keys.This description will be shown when accessing specific native API's.